# MongoDb Count after aggregation C# 2.0 driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I have the following aggregation pipline

```
var count = dbCollection.
Aggregate(new AggregateOptions { AllowDiskUse = true }).Match(query).
Group(groupby).
ToListAsync().Result.Count();
```

And this gets the following result:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "ProfileId" : ObjectId("55f6c727965bb016c81971ba")
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "ProfileId" : ObjectId("55f6c727965bb016c81971bb")
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

But it seems it will make count operation on client, but how to perform it in `MongoDb` ?
I have `MongoDb 2.0 C# driver` & `MongoDb v. 3.0.2`

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/csharp/aggregation/#group-documents-by-a-field-and-calculate-count

Comment: @ThrowsException the OP needs to count the number of results, not the counts for each _id

Comment: Can you give an example of your collection, and explain exactly what you want to count?   I am not clear on the goal of your query.     Also, please add the query and the groupby statements to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a constant field  to your group function and then group again on the constant field (so that all the results are grouped into a single group) with a aggregate sum of 1. The first (and only) result will have the sum.

Ex.

```
var count = dbCollection.
Aggregate(new AggregateOptions { AllowDiskUse = true }).Match(query).
Group(groupby).Group(<id>:{ConstantField},Total:{$sum:1})
ToListAsync().Result.First().GetValue("Total").
```